# I have many sections in my HTML markup using the same the classes, how can I use one function for each sections?

Tags: javascript, html, css, events, target

I have a product scroll sections on my site, because I used the same classes on the sections, When I scroll one section all section also scroll. How can I deal with this? Is there a way I can make my code flexible to accommodate this? If I'm to use event.target, where should I use them? for foreach? I only want each section to react to each function when its clicked. Below is my code

```js
function productScroll() {
  for (var x = 0; x < item.length; x++) {
    var allItem = item[x]
    console.log(allItem)
  }


  for (let b = 0; b < prev.length; b++) {

    prev[b].addEventListener("click", function() {
      if (slider_position > 0) {
        //avoid slide left beyond the first item
        slider_position -= 1;
        console.log("right is clicked")
        translateX(slider_position); //translate items
      }

    });

  }

  for (let i = 0; i < next.length; i++) {
    //refer elements by class name
    next[i].addEventListener("click", moveLeft, false);

  }


  function moveLeft() {


    if (node.slider_position >= 0 && node.slider_position < hiddenItems()) {
      //avoid slide right beyond the last item

      slider_position += 1;

      console.log("left is clicked")
      // e.target.style.display ="none"

      translateX(slider_position); //translate items


    };


  }


  function hiddenItems() {
    //get hidden items

    let items = getCount(allItem, false);

    for (var x = 0; x < slider.length; x++) {
      var visibleItems = slider[x].offsetWidth / 210;

      console.log(visibleItems)
      return items - Math.ceil(visibleItems);

    }


  }

}

function translateX(position) {
  //translate items
  for (var p = 0; p < item.length; p++) {
    item[p].style.left = position * -190 + "px";

    console.log(p)
  }


}

function getCount(parent, getChildrensChildren) {
  //count no of items
  let relevantChildren = 0;
  let children = parent.childNodes.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < children; i++) {
    console.log(children)
    if (parent.childNodes[i].nodeType != 3) {
      if (getChildrensChildren)
        relevantChildren += getCount(parent.childNodes[i], true);
      relevantChildren++;
    }
  }
  return relevantChildren;
}
```

```html
<section class="men_collections">
  <div class="slider container sliders" id="slider">
    <div class="slide slides " id="slide">
      <div class="item">
        <a href="www.google.com">
          <img src="/Assets/Asoso 1.png" style=" width:300px; height:400px;object-fit: cover;object-position: top;">
          <div class="sixteen_collection_text">
            <span>Object 1</span>
            <p>nice shoe in my leggs its very comfy and nice. what you see is not what you getnice shoe in my leggs its very comfy and nice. what you see is not what you get
              <span style="padding:0px 3px 0px 3px">-</span>Pavement Boot</p>
            <strong style="font-weight:400;">$129.99</strong>
          </div>
        </a>

      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <a href="www.google.com">
          <img src="/Assets/Asoso 1.png" style=" width:300px; height:400px;object-fit: cover;object-position: top;">
          <div class="sixteen_collection_text">
            <span>Object</span>
            <p>Flora<span style="padding:0px 3px 0px 3px">-</span>Pavement Boot</p>
            <strong style="font-weight:400;">$129.99</strong>
          </div>
        </a>

      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <a href="www.google.com">
          <img src="/Assets/Asoso 1.png" style=" width:300px; height:400px;object-fit: cover;object-position: top;">
          <div class="sixteen_collection_text">
            <span>Object</span>
            <p>Flora<span style="padding:0px 3px 0px 3px">-</span>Pavement Boot</p>
            <strong style="font-weight:400;">$129.99</strong>
          </div>
        </a>

      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <a href="www.google.com">
          <img src="/Assets/Asoso 1.png" style=" width:300px; height:400px;object-fit: cover;object-position: top;">
          <div class="sixteen_collection_text">
            <span>Object</span>
            <p>Flora<span style="padding:0px 3px 0px 3px">-</span>Pavement Boot</p>
            <strong style="font-weight:400;">$129.99</strong>
          </div>
        </a>

      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <a href="www.google.com">
          <img src="/Assets/Asoso 1.png" style=" width:300px; height:400px;object-fit: cover;object-position: top;">
          <div class="sixteen_collection_text">
            <span>Object</span>
            <p>Flora<span style="padding:0px 3px 0px 3px">-</span>Pavement Boot</p>
            <strong style="font-weight:400;">$129.99</strong>
          </div>
        </a>

      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <a href="www.google.com">
          <img src="/Assets/Asoso 1.png" style=" width:300px; height:400px;object-fit: cover;object-position: top;">
          <div class="sixteen_collection_text">
            <span>Object</span>
            <p>Flora<span style="padding:0px 3px 0px 3px">-</span>Pavement Boot</p>
            <strong style="font-weight:400;">$129.99</strong>
          </div>
        </a>

      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <a href="www.google.com">
          <img src="/Assets/Asoso 1.png" style=" width:300px; height:400px;object-fit: cover;object-position: top;">
          <div class="sixteen_collection_text">
            <span>Object</span>
            <p>Flora<span style="padding:0px 3px 0px 3px">-</span>Pavement Boot</p>
            <strong style="font-weight:400;">$129.99</strong>
          </div>
        </a>

      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <a href="www.google.com">
          <img src="/Assets/Asoso 1.png" style=" width:300px; height:400px;object-fit: cover;object-position: top;">
          <div class="sixteen_collection_text">
            <span>Object</span>
            <p>Flora<span style="padding:0px 3px 0px 3px">-</span>Pavement Boot</p>
            <strong style="font-weight:400;">$129.99</strong>
          </div>
        </a>

      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <a href="www.google.com">
          <img src="/Assets/Asoso3.png" style=" width:300px; height:400px;object-fit: cover;object-position: top;">
          <div class="sixteen_collection_text">
            <span>Object</span>
            <p>Flora<span style="padding:0px 3px 0px 3px">-</span>Pavement Boot</p>
            <strong style="font-weight:400;">$19.99</strong>
          </div>
        </a>

      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <a href="www.google.com">
          <img src="/Assets/Asoso3.png" style=" width:300px; height:400px;object-fit: cover;object-position: top;">
          <div class="sixteen_collection_text">
            <span>Object</span>
            <p>Flora<span style="padding:0px 3px 0px 3px">-</span>Pavement Boot</p>
            <strong style="font-weight:400;">$19.99</strong>
          </div>
        </a>

      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <a href="www.google.com">
          <img src="/Assets/jacket.png" style=" width:300px; height:400px;object-fit: cover;object-position: top;">
          <div class="sixteen_collection_text">
            <span>Object</span>
            <p>Flora<span style="padding:0px 3px 0px 3px">-</span>Pavement Boot</p>
            <strong style="font-weight:400;">$19.99</strong>
          </div>
        </a>

      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <a href="www.google.com">
          <img src="/Assets/jacket.png" style=" width:300px; height:400px;object-fit: cover;object-position: top;">
          <div class="sixteen_collection_text">
            <span>Object</span>
            <p>Flora<span style="padding:0px 3px 0px 3px">-</span>Pavement Boot</p>
            <strong style="font-weight:400;">$19.99</strong>
          </div>
        </a>

      </div>

    </div>
    <a class="prev ctrl-btn pro-prev"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    <a class="next ctrl-btn pro-next"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: Can you provide some functional HTML code?

Comment: I have edited the question and included the HTML markup.

Comment: If this is a commercial project, I suggest you to use SwipperJS: https://swiperjs.com/ which is a handy library to screate scrollable/carroussel content either individual or in groups, horizonal or vertical.

Answer (score 0):

Now, this is just a shot in the dark (since we don't have access to your full code), but try tweaking this line:

```
function translateX(position) {
  //translate items
  for (var p = 0; p < item.length; p++) {
    item[p].style.left = position * -190 + "px";

    console.log(p)
  }
}
```

to this:

```
function translateX(position) {
  //translate items
  for (var p = 0; p < item.length; p++) {
    item[p].style.left = ((p+1) * position * -190) + "px";    // <- here

    console.log(p)
  }
}
```